Unable to Share Deep Links in Expo App via Email
I am trying to implement deep linking in my Expo app to share links via email. I have configured the scheme in app.json and set up the necessary prefixes and screen paths in my navigation container using expo-linking. However, I'm facing issues getting the deep linking to work
properly. Here are the steps I've taken so far:

Configured app.json:



{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "myapp",
    "platforms": ["ios", "android"],
    ...
  }
}




Set up navigation container with expo-linking:



import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const prefix = Linking.createURL('/');

const linking = {
  prefixes: [prefix],
  config: {
    screens: {
      Home: '',
      Details: 'details/:id',
    },
  },
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer linking={linking}>
      {/* Rest of your navigation stack */}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}



Despite these configurations, the link does not seem to open the app or navigate to the correct screen. When I click the link from the email, it either opens the app's main screen or does nothing at all.
Have I missed any crucial steps in the configuration for deep linking in Expo?
Are there any additional settings required for handling deep links specifically for email sharing?
How can I debug and verify that the deep link is correctly configured and working?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
